# DRUPAL, Views: I cannot change theme from Views settings

Tags: drupal, view

I cannot change the css theme of my Drupal View. This is a screenshots of the settings:
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/72686/viewTheme.png

I've tried all buttons, I cannot save the new theme (BlueMarine) in the preferences. It is stuck on Zen (which is my front-end theme).

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That dropdown in the image you link to is only showing you what the appropriate template files are in each theme. If you want advanced theming you could use something like http://drupal.org/project/themekey, or customise an existing theme.

Comment: Ok thanks, but how is this related to Views ? I mean, why are the drupal theme informations inside the View module ?

Comment: The theme layer sits on top of everything, the Views module is just being a good Drupal citizen by exposing everything it does to the theming engine. (Lots of modules are ready-made for theming but don't go to the effort that Views does in advertising this. Install devel module and turn on theme developer if you want to see the full picture)

Answer (score 0):

What you see there is not a setting to change the theme of the view, but a tool to see what template files views can find and will use. You can use it to figure out what to name your template files you want to use for overrides. Views let you select which theme you want to see what template files will be used. The label also explains what it is used for very well: `Theming infomation`. It also states that

> This section lists all the possible templates...